# Autofill conditional format in shared workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I made a code that will use the range.autofill to extend the sheet until it reached column "DO".
The code is running fine, but only when the file is shared (which is meant to be). the conditional format is not working. Somehow the autofill function in VBA is forgetting the conditional format when the workbook is shared.

It's not an option to disable the shared workbook because other people can be in the file, and the file can not be overwritten when they are in the file (I think?)

Does someone know a workaround?

This is my code:

```
    Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

    lColumn = 20
    For iCntr = lColumn To 13 Step -1 '12 is de eerste kolom in dit geval kolom M
        If Cells(3, iCntr) = 0 Then '3 is de rij waar de 0 of 1 wordt gepresenteerd
        Columns(iCntr).Delete
End If
Next

With Workbooks("Bureauplanning.xlsm").Worksheets("Planning")
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, -3).EntireColumn

Dim rngEnd As Range
Set rngEnd = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).EntireColumn

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = .Range(rngStart, .Columns("DO"))

Dim rngX As Range
Set rngX = .Range(rngStart, rngEnd)

End With

If Range("DO3") <> 0 Then GoTo volgende
rngX.AutoFill rng, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, I mentioned that is was a table indeed but I meant just a sheet. It's not a  table so it won't work I'm afraid.

Comment: You can create a dynamic named range that will extend as you add rows and apply formatting to that named range. Or, consider if can be a table.

Comment: mmh it cant be a table. When updating the sheet mostly the first column of the sheet is getting deleted, so the last column ("DO") will be a fresh column and the conditional format is not working then

Comment: Conditional formatting is one of the problematic/limited features in shared workbooks. I can't find the link on a Microsoft site, but it's mentioned [here](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2008/11/18/avoiding-shared-workbooks-in-excel/).

Comment: Seems like I gave bad advice. Apologies.